# Why would I have so many rejected shares while mining?

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, cgminer, mining-pool-shares

I am mining litecoin with give-me-coins and I have the following info on website's stats section

```
 Valid Paid: 118
 Invalid (Not Paid): 113 (95.76%)
```

As far as I know this is not very good.

How can I make it better ?

I use cgminer 3.7.2 (used 3.6.6 also) with following command

```
cgminer --scrypt -o ltc-eu.give-me-coins.com:3333 -u user.pass -p x -I 11
```

Comment: What are you mining with? Usually the pool will tell you more specifically - often it's because your connection is unstable and the shares went stale by the time you submitted them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try decreasing your intensity. Other parameters can also lower speed and decrease/remove failures. It's like running too eagerly, it might make you trip a lot.

It could also be your Internet connection or even give-me-coins itself (although I doubt it's give-me-coins itself).